# Can't write to S3 using PySpark - AmazonS3Exception with status code 400 (InvalidPart)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a simple spark job which does 3 things:

1. Read json data month-by-month from AWS S3 (Data is partitioned by date).
2. Do some minimal processing on the data.
3. Overwrite the processed monthly data to the same source.

The job successfully processes and overwrites few month but is randomly raising this exception while overwriting to S3:

> Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: One or more of the specified parts could not be found.  The part may not have been uploaded, or the specified entity tag may not match the part's entity tag. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidPart; Request ID: 123; S3 Extended Request ID: xyz/ck+foo/bar=)

Here is the code snippet of the PySpark Job:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('simple_app').getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")

source_data_lake_path = "s3://my-data-lake/data"
months_not_found, months_cleaned = [], []

for month in ['2020-01-*', '2020-02-*', '2020-03-*', ....]:
    try:
        data = spark.read.json(f"{source_data_lake_path}/persist_date={month}")
    except AnalysisException:
        months_not_found.append(month)
        continue
    cleaned_data, cleaned = clean_data(data)
    if cleaned:
        cleaned_data = cleaned_data.withColumn("persist_date", F.to_date(F.col("persist_timestamp")))
        cleaned_data.repartition("persist_date").write.partitionBy("persist_date").mode("overwrite").json(
            source_data_lake_path
        )
        months_cleaned.append(month)
```

My Findings:

1. Use s3:// because s3:// and s3n:// are functionally interchangeable in the context of AWS EMR, while s3a:// is not compatible with EMR.
2. I thought that this is because of multiple concurrent writes and reduced the number of nodes. Still the job sometimes randomly fails due to this Exception.

Comment: How many partitions? It seems that your multi-part upload is failed. S3 has the api limit, for example 3500 requests per second for the same prefix PUT request.

Comment: @Lamanus I don't know if this is the correct answer to your question but there is one partition for every date, so approx. 30 per month. Is there any way to stay within the API limit and still be able to overwrite all this data?

Comment: Hello Gaurav, was you able to figure out and fix the root cause behind this issue. I'm in similar situation and trying to figure out probable root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this myself, but at a guess:

*while your client is uploading data, another process is listing and aborting incomplete uploads on the bucket.*

This could be because

- it is done explicitly from the cli or other application
- the bucket is set to automatically delete incomplete uploads after a period (e.g 24h)
- some other job is writing to the same path and its committer is listing and aborting uploads.

To see if this is the cause, enable logging for the bucket, then look at the logs at the time the incidents occur and look for `"REST.DELETE.UPLOAD"` entries in the log. Find out who is doing this and tell them to stop it.

Comment: Note, the ASF S3A Connector covers a similar-but-not-identical stack trace https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#When_writing_data:_.E2.80.9Cjava.io.FileNotFoundException:_Completing_multi-part_upload.E2.80.9D